# Ability to toggle all animations/transitions/fades in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, animation, toggle

I have an application that uses jQuery to transition/fade/animate elements within the UI (ie a panel will slide out from the side when it is toggled to be visible). I would like to give the user the option to toggle all of the 'effects' via a checkbox, depending on how they would like to set up the workflow of the application.

So instead of *Hidden state > Effect/Transition > Visible state* I would like *Hidden state > Visible state* based on whether transitions are enabled (most likely via a checkbox).

Is this possible without rewriting all of the hidden/visible states based on the checkbox? Is there some form of select-all that would remove the effect?

Comment: It may help to provide your relevant code so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can globally turn off all jQuery animations by changing the value of:

```
jQuery.fx.off
```

as in:

```
// disable all jQuery animations so they immediately jump to the end state
jQuery.fx.off = true;
```

jQuery doc [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.fx.off/).

Answer (score 0):

> Animations may be stopped globally by setting the property `$.fx.off` to true. When this is done, all animation methods will immediately set elements to their final state when called, rather than displaying an effect.

source: [jQuery API docs](http://api.jquery.com/finish/)